# Do I need to keep the comment at the end when I copy SSH public keys to another machine?

Tags: linux, ssh, authentication, ssh-keys, rsa

Say I have a public RSA SSH key that looks like:

```
ssh-rsa ijvoienvejfvmiejnci3onrvejviewlonvcljnrijcnreionv me@machine
```

If I’m copying this key to share with another machine, do I include the comment at the end (`me@machine`)? Do I include the header (`ssh-rsa`)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Header yes, comment - up to you;

The header tells of the encryption used, and while it maybe possible to figure it out, it's easier this way ;)

As for the comment at the end, you can keep it, get rid of it or change it as you want.

Comment: The comment is handy when looking at an `authorized_keys` file to pick up at a glance which keys are authorized.

Comment: It is not encryption. It is "just" the key type, but it does not mean it is less important.